# replicate call to start nginx in Dockerfile from docker-compose

Tags: docker, nginx

I have the following Dockerfile that does work:

```
FROM nginx:1.15.2-alpine
COPY ./build /var/www
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
EXPOSE 80
ENTRYPOINT ["nginx","-g","daemon off;"]
```

I need to replicate this in docker-compose.

I'd like to specify the same image as the `FROM` instruction above.

I don't know where to put the `COPY` commands in docker-compose and I don't think `ENTRYPOINT` is what I am after in docker-compose

Comment: I’d use the Docker Compose `build:` directive to point at your existing Dockerfile.  In particular `COPY` doesn’t have a direct Docker Compose or `docker run` equivalent.

Comment: docker-compose uses your Dockerfile so no need for `COPY`

Comment: The annoying thing is the `context`, the files need to be inside the context

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to redefine the entrypoint when using docker-compose, it will be taken from the base nginx image. You can use bind mounts instead of `COPY`. E.g. like this (not tested):

```
nginx:
  image: "nginx:1.15.2-alpine"
  container_name: nginx
  volumes:
    - ./build:/var/www
    - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
  ports:
    - "80:80"
```

Of course, the `ports` part will already go beyond the Dockerfile and actually publish the port, you can leave that out.